# How to debug Project Tango C examples

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, ubuntu-14.04, google-project-tango

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I cloned the c examples github repo. I have ADT Eclipse installed, and I also installed C/C++ plugins. I can import the example projects as Android projects. I tried the PointCloud example and the augmented reality example so far. I can start a debug session as an Android app, and I can select my Tango tablet device. I can see this error messages on the top in logcat view:

`01-20 00:09:05.583: A/art(5250): art/runtime/thread.cc:1011] No pending exception expected: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load point_cloud_jni_example from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/libtango_device.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.projecttango.experiments.nativepointcloud-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.projecttango.experiments.nativepointcloud-1, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null`

At the same time on the tablet I'm presented with the dialog to give rights to the app, which I give, but then the app immediately stops.

1. Should I use Eclipse ADT, or can I use Android Studio (IntelliJ) somehow?
2. Should I import the projects as Android projects? (I think yes).

What looks weird in the error message to me is mention of dalvik. I thought Tango applications should be ART ones, but the error message mentions Dalvik (while seemingly the ART runtime tries to load it). Is that the problem? How can I fix that?

Comment: I managed to run the Java PointCloud sample. It's interesting that for a while I saw an error message complaining about API 19. That's the target SDK version in the manifest, that's really not ART. Then I needed to compile the TangoUtils, and I placed it in the lib. But all of that is the Java examples, I'd like to get going with C.

Comment: I have NDK installed too, I guess I need to do some build for the JNI part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I just needed to do some homework. As described here: https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/c-getting-started

1. I changed the current directory to the desired C example project (root). Then I had to say `<ndk_path>/ndk-build`. That compiled the `so` files containing the `JNI` related part. For example in case of the `point-cloud-jni-example`, within the `libs` directory an `armabi-v7a` directory is created and within that a `libpoint_cloud_jni_example.so` and a `libtango_client_api.so` file is created/compiled/placed. Note that I had the NDK installed already.
2. I reopened the project in ADT Eclipse and refreshed (right click in the Project explorer on the root node and refresh). After that I still had an error message, that it cannot find the Android manifest. Which is stupid, because it's right there. To trigger some action I adjusted the target SDK version to 20 in the Android manifest. Note that if you set the minimum SDK version to 20, the Tango device won't show up in the AVD, because it's API level is 19, just sayin' :)

Anyhow, after that I managed to run the project as an Android app. Also note that the github repo referenced in the c-getting-started does not exist any more. We can say that the "hello world" is now the `hello-tango-jni-example` project.

Comment: In one line: I just needed to compile the JNI part.

Comment: Also, you can easily spot if you don't have the JNI parts in the apk. Before the fix it was 24K, after that it became 319K.

Answer (score 1):

I finally gave up on Android Studio - I managed to keep moving until I had to bring in the tango shared library, simply could not find a way to convince gradle to link it -  and too many comments out there were on the order of

> the ndk integration is busted, long live the new ndk at some vague future point

I'm on Windows, and finally ended up springing for VisualGDB, which allows the use of eclipse for the java side and visual studio on the native side - probably could have done it with eclipse but visual studio is an old friend.  Since you're on Ubuntu, you should have alternatives in gdb interfaces.

Comment: Waaat? That's sounds worse than I thought. I'll tinker tonight.

Comment: What do you mean by "the ndk is busted"? What's wrong with it?

Comment: BTW, it's interesting, that the AndroidManifest targets API 19, the project includes a 4.4W android.jar, and tutorials speak about API 20 NDK when compiling. o_O

Comment: @CsabaToth -  amended comment - it's issues with gradles integration of the ndk - the ndk itself is fine

Comment: thanks - I really really wanted to succeed with AS, it just wasn't in the cards at the time  -  course, they did warn us this wasn't quite ready for prime time